# background worker not responding in our code

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

i have following code  and telerik grid my records are  1266880 background worker are hangout for one minutes i try many ways but cannot success anyone know my application does not hang

```
PopulateUI(List<DataRow> list)
{
     this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        int Count = list.Count;
                        grdFares.RowCount = Count;
                        // grdFares.BeginUpdate();

                        for (int i = 0; i < grdFares.RowCount; i++)
                        {

                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.Id].Value = list[i].ItemArray[0].ToStr();
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.FROMLOCATION].Value = list[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.TOLOCATION].Value = list[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.FARE].Value = list[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.RowNo].Value = 0;
                            //  grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.OrignTypeId].Value = list[i].OriginLocationTypeId;
                            //   grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.DestinationTypeId].Value = list[i].DestinationLocationTypeId;
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.VehicleType].Value = list[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
                            grdFares.Rows[i].Cells[COLS.VehicleId].Value = list[i].ItemArray[11].ToString();


                        }
                            }));

         }
```

Comment: How many `grdFares.RowCount` do you have?

Comment: Loading 1,266,880 records is really wrong. Load your data page by page per user request.

Comment: In addition, a `List<DataRow>` is twice the bad.  Use `DataTable` and DataBinding, which your grid should support natively.  The way you are going is doomed to fail miserably.